# How does Flutter GetX Detects that a observables has been used in a Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, observable, flutter-getx

In Getx when we write:

```
Obx(() => Text(controller.someObservable.value));
```

How does it know there was an observable used in the code?

Is there some dart feature that lets us read the code programmatically, or it uses language parsing to detect the injected observable?

For example it is easy to detect observable if getx used this method of detecting,
As observable is passed directly

```
Obx((value) => Text(value), obs: controller.someObservable);
```

However what seems to be happening is that GetX just reads the code and detects injected observable.

Comment: Well, the GetX package is open source. You could dig in the code and investigate it

Comment: Getx is quite big, it will take a lot of my time to understand it. i'll try it when i'm free. Meanwhile I have asked the question as i'm completely confused about this.